# Intelli-J: cannot create class-file?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, naming

This is honestly a tiny problem but it's keeping me from proceeding with my small Java practice app.

I'm currently practicing making an API call in Java. I was trying to create a simple class file called "Film". However, when I try to create it as a class-file, Intelli-J keeps telling me that it is unable to create a class-file. I'm trying to set this file up in a folder called "models". All of these class files are going to be utilized as part of an app that performs API calls.

Is there some naming convention I haven't followed? I've been Googling but haven't really found anything.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to make a literal `.class` file? That's the only thing I can think of that would cause it to complain like that. Your Java files that contain your classes should be all `.java`. The `.class` files are created by the java compiler, not by the programmer directly.

Answer (score 18):

More directly, based on what @Vishal Jumani  touched on, you need to tell IntelliJ what directories are 'source' or 'test' directories.

A directory structure you can use as an example, but you can use whatever you wish.

[image]

Right click on the directory you wish to mark as 'root' --> find 'Mark Directory As' --> Select 'Sources Root'

[image]

Now you should be able to add java classes in the directory without IntelliJ interrupting you!

Answer (score 8):

This would usually be because of the way your project is setup. It may not be setup correctly to indicate where your source code is.

- To setup your project, in the Project Tab, click on the top most folder and select F4. This should bring up the Project Settings dialog window.
- Now click on Modules in the LHS, and then select the Sources Tab on the RHS
- Select your src folder and click on the Sources button, to indicate this is your source folder. Now IntelliJ is aware that this is where your code is.
- Click on Apply and OK. This should close the Dialog Window.
- Now right click on the src folder and then select New -> Java Class to create your Java class